# Python+SciKit -> different results for manual and cross_val_score prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kaggle

I am performing learning tasks from Kaggle for case with Titanic.

I have different prediction accuracy if I perform linear regression manually separating data or with cross_val_score. The same is for logistic regression.

**Example.**

**- Linear regression.**

Manual

```
Algorithm = LinearRegression()
kf = KFold(dataset.shape[0], n_folds=3, random_state=1)
predictions = []

for train, test in kf:

    train_predictors = (dataset[Predictors].iloc[train])
    train_target = dataset['Survived'].iloc[train]
    Algorithm.fit(train_predictors, train_target)
    test_predictions = Algorithm.predict(dataset[Predictors].iloc[test])
    predictions.append(test_predictions)

predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)
print(predictions.shape[0])
realed = list(dataset.Survived)
predictions[predictions > 0.5] = 1
predictions[predictions <= 0.5] = 0

accuracy2 = sum(predictions[predictions == dataset["Survived"]]) / len(predictions)
print("Tochnost prognoza: ", accuracy2 * 100, " %")
```

**Result - 78,34%**

Cross_val_score

```
scores=cross_val_score(LinearRegression(), dataset[Predictors], dataset["Survived"], cv=3)
print(scores.mean())
```

**Result - 37,5%**

**- Logistic regression.**

Here I have 26,15% for manual and 78,78% for cross_val_score function.

Why??

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that look quite wrong about your code.

1. **Your accuracy computation is wrong**.
   This line:

   ```
   accuracy2 = sum(predictions[predictions == dataset["Survived"]]) / len(predictions)
   ```

   does not compute the accuracy. What it does is take the mean of the predictions you made when you have the right prediction. Which does not make a lot of sense ;).
   This is easy to fix though:

   ```
   accuracy2 = sum(predictions == dataset["Survived"] / len(predictions)
   ```
2. **Linear regression actually performs regression**.
   It is not a good idea to use linear regression to perform a classification task. In (binary) classification you expect an output in the range [0; 1] (probabilities), while linear regression typically gives you an infinite range.
   As statisticians were big fans of linear regression they invented logistic regression, which really is a linear regression on a transformed target value.
   **Bottom line**: use logistic regression (not linear regression) for classification.
3. **The score methods are not those you think**.
   `cross_val_score` takes a `scoring` parameter. Here you did not specify it (so it's `None`) and it means that it will look up the default score method of the estimator. The default score method for `LinearRegression` **is not accuracy**. It is the R^2 coefficient. This is relevant in regression, not really in what you are trying to do.

   So when you do this:

   ```
   scores=cross_val_score(LinearRegression(), dataset[Predictors], dataset["Survived"], cv=3)
   print(scores.mean())
   ```

   What you're getting is the average R^2 coefficient on a 3-fold cross validation.
   When you do it with `LogisticRegression` you get the average accuracy, which is what you wanted.

Points 1 and 2 explain the results you get with `LogisticRegression` and with `cross_val_score` on `LinearRegression`.
I'm not sure about the first case yet, I'll update my post if I find a good explanation. I find it **very** surprising because the mistake you made in computing accuracy should always *underestimate* the result.  Unless this is not the actual code you ran of course.

Comment: +1.  And I am wondering, why a person who took time to write such detailed, clear and useful answer did not bother to come up with some unique name for him/her-self beyond "user......."